# Javascript is not working for "onchange" event in a dropdown inside a <div> section with "id"

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a DropDownList `<select>` with an `onchange="Prueba();"` javascript event.

This DropDown is inside a `<div>`. This `<div>` has an `id=` that receives a very complex (at least, for me) Javascript event, from a ".js" file. This complex event affects the `<select>`, giving to it a different behaviour than default. I want to conserve this different behaviour.

### Problem:

This `<div>` **ID** "blocks" my `onchange="Prueba();"` event in the DropDown.

**If I take out the ID, my event works fine**, but I loose the behaviour from the .js file, and I don't want to miss that.

### Question:

Im not very used to javascript. That's why I can't find how to fix this. Could anybody help me?

### My event:

```
function Prueba() {
            var Lista = document.getElementById("ListaBotones");
            var Cambio1 = document.getElementById("Cambio");
            var Cambio = Cambio1.options[Cambio1.selectedIndex].text;
            var Cosa1 = document.getElementById("Cosa");
            var Cosa = Cosa1.options[Cosa1.selectedIndex].text;

            if (Cambio == "CREATE") {
                if (Cosa == "LPAR") {
                    Lista.children[1].style.display = 'inline';
                    Lista.children[2].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[3].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[4].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[5].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[6].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[7].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[8].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[9].style.display = "none";
                }
                if (Cosa == "DEALER") {
                    Lista.children[1].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[2].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[3].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[4].style.display = 'inline';
                    Lista.children[5].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[6].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[7].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[8].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[9].style.display = "none";
                }
                if (Cosa == "BATCH") {
                    Lista.children[1].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[2].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[3].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[4].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[5].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[6].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[7].style.display = 'inline';
                    Lista.children[8].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[9].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
            if (Cambio == "MODIFY") {
                if (Cosa == "LPAR") {
                    Lista.children[1].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[2].style.display = 'inline';
                    Lista.children[3].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[4].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[5].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[6].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[7].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[8].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[9].style.display = "none";
                }
                if (Cosa == "DEALER") {
                    Lista.children[1].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[2].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[3].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[4].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[5].style.display = 'inline';
                    Lista.children[6].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[7].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[8].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[9].style.display = "none";
                }
                if (Cosa == "BATCH") {
                    Lista.children[1].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[2].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[3].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[4].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[5].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[6].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[7].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[8].style.display = 'inline';
                    Lista.children[9].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
            if (Cambio == "DELETE") {
                if (Cosa == "LPAR") {
                    Lista.children[1].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[2].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[3].style.display = 'inline';
                    Lista.children[4].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[5].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[6].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[7].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[8].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[9].style.display = "none";
                }
                if (Cosa == "DEALER") {
                    Lista.children[1].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[2].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[3].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[4].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[5].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[6].style.display = 'inline';
                    Lista.children[7].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[8].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[9].style.display = "none";
                }
                if (Cosa == "BATCH") {
                    Lista.children[1].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[2].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[3].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[4].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[5].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[6].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[7].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[8].style.display = "none";
                    Lista.children[9].style.display = 'inline';
                }
            }
        }
```

### DIV in aspx form:

```
<div id="nl-form" class="nl-form" style="text-align: center">
        I want to
    <select id="Cambio" onchange="Prueba();">
        <option value="1" selected>CREATE </option>
        <option value="2">MODIFY </option>
        <option value="3">DELETE </option>
    </select>
        a
        <select id="Cosa" onchange="Prueba();">
            <option value="1" selected>LPAR</option>
            <option value="2">DEALER</option>
            <option value="3">BATCH</option>
        </select>
        Definition.
    </div>
```

### SCRIPT (in aspx file):

```
<script src="../js/nlform.js"></script>
    <script>
        var nlform = new NLForm(document.getElementById('nl-form'));
    </script>
```

### NLFORM.JS File:

```
; (
    function (window) {

    'use strict';

    var document = window.document;

    if (!String.prototype.trim) {
        String.prototype.trim=function(){return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');};
    }

    function NLForm( el ) { 
        this.el = el;
        this.overlay = this.el.querySelector( '.nl-overlay' );
        this.fields = [];
        this.fldOpen = -1;
        this._init();
    }

    NLForm.prototype = {
        _init : function() {
            var self = this;
            Array.prototype.slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( 'select' ) ).forEach( function( el, i ) {
                self.fldOpen++;
                self.fields.push( new NLField( self, el, 'dropdown', self.fldOpen ) );
            } );
            Array.prototype.slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( 'input' ) ).forEach( function( el, i ) {
                self.fldOpen++;
                self.fields.push( new NLField( self, el, 'input', self.fldOpen ) );
            } );
            this.overlay.addEventListener('click', function (ev) { self._closeFlds(); });
            this.overlay.addEventListener( 'touchstart', function(ev) { self._closeFlds(); } );
        },
        _closeFlds : function() {
            if( this.fldOpen !== -1 ) {
                this.fields[ this.fldOpen ].close();
            }
        }
    }

    function NLField( form, el, type, idx ) {
        this.form = form;
        this.elOriginal = el;
        this.pos = idx;
        this.type = type;
        this._create();
        this._initEvents();
    }

    NLField.prototype = {
        _create : function() {
            if( this.type === 'dropdown' ) {
                this._createDropDown(); 
            }
            else if( this.type === 'input' ) {
                this._createInput();    
            }
        },
        _createDropDown : function() {
            var self = this;
            this.fld = document.createElement( 'div' );
            this.fld.className = 'nl-field nl-dd';
            this.toggle = document.createElement( 'a' );
            this.toggle.innerHTML = this.elOriginal.options[ this.elOriginal.selectedIndex ].innerHTML;
            this.toggle.className = 'nl-field-toggle';
            this.optionsList = document.createElement( 'ul' );
            var ihtml = '';
            Array.prototype.slice.call( this.elOriginal.querySelectorAll( 'option' ) ).forEach( function( el, i ) {
                ihtml += self.elOriginal.selectedIndex === i ? '<li class="nl-dd-checked">' + el.innerHTML + '</li>' : '<li>' + el.innerHTML + '</li>';
                // selected index value
                if( self.elOriginal.selectedIndex === i ) {
                    self.selectedIdx = i;
                }
            } );
            this.optionsList.innerHTML = ihtml;
            this.fld.appendChild( this.toggle );
            this.fld.appendChild( this.optionsList );
            this.elOriginal.parentNode.insertBefore( this.fld, this.elOriginal );
            this.elOriginal.style.display = 'none';
        },
        _createInput : function() {
            var self = this;
            this.fld = document.createElement( 'div' );
            this.fld.className = 'nl-field nl-ti-text';
            this.toggle = document.createElement( 'a' );
            this.toggle.innerHTML = this.elOriginal.getAttribute( 'placeholder' );
            this.toggle.className = 'nl-field-toggle';
            this.optionsList = document.createElement( 'ul' );
            this.getinput = document.createElement( 'input' );
            this.getinput.setAttribute( 'type', 'text' );
            this.getinput.setAttribute( 'placeholder', this.elOriginal.getAttribute( 'placeholder' ) );
            this.getinputWrapper = document.createElement( 'li' );
            this.getinputWrapper.className = 'nl-ti-input';
            this.inputsubmit = document.createElement( 'button' );
            this.inputsubmit.className = 'nl-field-go';
            this.inputsubmit.innerHTML = 'Go';
            this.getinputWrapper.appendChild( this.getinput );
            this.getinputWrapper.appendChild( this.inputsubmit );
            this.example = document.createElement( 'li' );
            this.example.className = 'nl-ti-example';
            this.example.innerHTML = this.elOriginal.getAttribute( 'data-subline' );
            this.optionsList.appendChild( this.getinputWrapper );
            this.optionsList.appendChild( this.example );
            this.fld.appendChild( this.toggle );
            this.fld.appendChild( this.optionsList );
            this.elOriginal.parentNode.insertBefore( this.fld, this.elOriginal );
            this.elOriginal.style.display = 'none';
        },
        _initEvents : function() {
            var self = this;
            this.toggle.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) { ev.preventDefault(); ev.stopPropagation(); self._open(); } );
            this.toggle.addEventListener( 'touchstart', function( ev ) { ev.preventDefault(); ev.stopPropagation(); self._open(); } );

            if( this.type === 'dropdown' ) {
                var opts = Array.prototype.slice.call( this.optionsList.querySelectorAll( 'li' ) );
                opts.forEach( function( el, i ) {
                    el.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) { ev.preventDefault(); self.close( el, opts.indexOf( el ) ); } );
                    el.addEventListener( 'touchstart', function( ev ) { ev.preventDefault(); self.close( el, opts.indexOf( el ) ); } );
                } );
            }
            else if( this.type === 'input' ) {
                this.getinput.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( ev ) {
                    if ( ev.keyCode == 13 ) {
                        self.close();
                    }
                } );
                this.inputsubmit.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) { ev.preventDefault(); self.close(); } );
                this.inputsubmit.addEventListener( 'touchstart', function( ev ) { ev.preventDefault(); self.close(); } );
            }

        },
        _open : function() {
            if( this.open ) {
                return false;
            }
            this.open = true;
            this.form.fldOpen = this.pos;
            var self = this;
            this.fld.className += ' nl-field-open';
        },
        close : function( opt, idx ) {
            if( !this.open ) {
                return false;
            }
            this.open = false;
            this.form.fldOpen = -1;
            this.fld.className = this.fld.className.replace(/\b nl-field-open\b/,'');

            if( this.type === 'dropdown' ) {
                if( opt ) {
                    // remove class nl-dd-checked from previous option
                    var selectedopt = this.optionsList.children[ this.selectedIdx ];
                    selectedopt.className = '';
                    opt.className = 'nl-dd-checked';
                    this.toggle.innerHTML = opt.innerHTML;
                    // update selected index value
                    this.selectedIdx = idx;
                    // update original select element´s value
                    this.elOriginal.value = this.elOriginal.children[ this.selectedIdx ].value;
                }
            }
            else if( this.type === 'input' ) {
                this.getinput.blur();
                this.toggle.innerHTML = this.getinput.value.trim() !== '' ? this.getinput.value : this.getinput.getAttribute( 'placeholder' );
                this.elOriginal.value = this.getinput.value;
            }
        }
    }

    // add to global namespace
    window.NLForm = NLForm;

} )( window );
```

Comment: Why not use `addEventListener` rather than the `onchange` attribute?

Comment: Is this structure ok?

`var Cosa1 = document.getElementById("Cosa"); Cosa1.addEventListener("change", function() {alert("Hello World");});`

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not write script after `</body>`, so, when page load on script, there have not defined dom object "nl-form" and "Cambio" and "Cosa"